# any workaround to re-write the jquery code to work in a different context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

html :

```
<div id="dialog" style="border:1px solid green; width:150px; margin:auto;">

<br />
<div class="dialog_insider" style=" border:1px solid red; width:120px; margin:auto; display:none;">

this is dialog insider
</div><!-- end of id  dialog_insider-->

<br />

</div>
```

javascript / jquery code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //$(".dialog_insider", my_dialog).click(function(){

    $(".dialog_insider").click(function(){

        alert("this is an alert box");  
    });

    $("#dialog").click(function(){

        my_dialog=  $(this).clone();
        my_dialog.dialog();

        $(".dialog_insider", my_dialog).css('display','block');
    });
});
```

Clicking on the dialog box on 'dialog_insider' div no longer shows the alert box. To show it there I have to remove the following snippet

```
$(".dialog_insider").click(function(){

     alert("this is an alert box");  
});
```

and place it in the following way :

```
$("#dialog").click(function(){

    my_dialog=  $(this).clone();
    my_dialog.dialog();

    $(".dialog_insider", my_dialog).css('display','block');

    $(".dialog_insider", my_dialog).click(function(){
        alert("this is an alert box");  
    });
});
```

I know that much. My questions are:

1. What is the concept of context here that the former coding pattern won't cover up the 'dialog_insider' div on the dialog box?
2. If the amount of code to be re-written to work in a different context is large, then is there any workaround so that i could easily make the code work in a different context without having to re-write all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are creating a new element and inserting it into the DOM via clone(). The 'click' handler is not bound to dynamically created elements. You will need to switch to `.on( 'click', function() { ... } );` and use delegated events (jQuery >=1.7)

Here is [an updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3U2BR/). Check out the [documentation for the on() here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Please note that you should

> Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents.

Comment: i think, being pervasive or not in nature is only about event handlers , not about selectors. Am I right?

Comment: From the documentation you linked: `Use of the .live() method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its drawbacks.` Please don't suggest it any more. It is **deprecated**.

Comment: I think what I should've said is that dynamically created elements are not bound by click handlers since they are not part of the initial DOM. That should make more sense.

Comment: @bazmegakapa Thanks for the information. I've updated my answer to reflect that.